# Barcode scanner with USB port display wrong charactar on Windows 7 and XP

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, windows-xp

For sometimes I did not have issue with my barcode scanner when I'm using it on Ubuntu or Windows 10 on my laptop (64 bits) but now that I want to put the program I was developing on production (On windows 7 or XP), I realise that it does not work and when debuging, I find out that the barcode scanner does not input the same string (set of 13 digits for EAN 13 ) as it usually does with ubuntu or Windows 10 on my laptop rather, some string like `CWC_""aL-S` ... I'm completly confuse and don't yet know how to fixe this. You can see the picture of the barcode scanner attached to my post 
[image: the barcode scanner device]

Comment: There's usually a sheet of barcodes that comes with the scanner, that sheet includes codes to switch the mode of the scanner.

Comment: Yes you're right but I've did not have it with me thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution: as the barcode scanner input the string as if someone were type on the keyboard of the computer, then the keyboard have to be configure in english (in my case) so that the barcode scanner can input the right result otherwise, it will be like someone is trying to use AZERTY keyboard as QWERTY to intput a number That is it.. I've read it from [this post](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Barcode-Reader-USB-HID-Interface-text-entry-without-Window/td-p/1129733)